# Regex to replace a substring in java

Tags: java, regex

I have a list containing strings like below

```
/b/Xfassds12312/5324234/img1.jpg
/b/asda33CSds/765345/img1.jpg
/b/iop98plkKLJ/2421466/img1.jpg
/b/nzcbWWSJk/3424535/img1.jpg
```

I need to replace the `/b/` to `/img/` in every string of that list.

I tried the below pattern.. looks like it appending instead of replacing.. not sure what I'm missing

`replaceFirst("(/[^/]*)", "$1" + "img");`

Comment: What do you think the $1 is doing?

Comment: Why not: `replaceFirst("/[^/]*", "/img");` ?

Comment: @anubhava It removes the first slash too

Comment: Why use regex at all? Are there other Strings in your list that would return a wrong result for a simple `replace("/b/", "/img/")`?

Comment: @Jeeppp: It should be `/img` in replacement. Reload to see my changes.

Comment: Your code is working fine. Checkout here https://onlinegdb.com/H1l5vHsyP

PS : I suspect your $1

Comment: `replaceFirst("(/)[^/]*", "$1img");`. `$1` is a backreference to Group 1 value.

Comment: in this case it's simple to use replace() method instead of regular expression

Comment: Maybe even substring? `String o = "/img/" + s.substring(3);` where s is your input string.

Comment: Show your desired result.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If the other strings would not breaks, just use `yourString.replace("/b/", "/img/");`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
String output = yourString.replaceFirst("^/[^/]+", "/img");
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/0dTPMv/1).

VISUAL:

[image]

EXPLANATION:

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  /                        '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^/]+                    any character except: '/' (1 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
```